# Android RecyclerView - in Adapter set ImageView height

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm using the `RecyclerView` and want to render images in a horizontal list. The main problem is, that I want to scale the images to the height of the `RecyclerView` while loading, as seen http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

The `parent` (the `RecyclerView`) in `onCreateViewHolder` reports the incorrect `getMeasuredHeight`. It's too big (complete screen height?). I add the `Adapter` in the `onResume` method of my fragment to the `RecyclerView`.

How do I get the height of my `RecyclerView`, which has current 2/3 of the screen height (may change with a new layout-file)?

Edit: It seems, that the `parent` height is correct.

Comment: recyclerView.getHeight() ?

Comment: rV.getHeight (and parent.getHeight) is always 0. - Maybe I follow the wrong path, but how can I do it then?

Comment: try using instead your LayoutManager and call .getHeight() on this...

Comment: ??? The `Adapter` has no connection to the `LayoutManager` and I need the height in `Adapter.onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: See suggestion below, i don't see why that can't work..

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OnPreDrawListener. In the listener you can get the measured height of the RecyclerView and trigger the load.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

     ImageView mImageView;
     int imageHeight;
     public MyViewHolder(View view){
         super(view);

         mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

         // set the imageHeight from the ImageView
         imageHeight = mImageView.getHeight();
     }

     // Create this public method
     public int getImageHeight(){
         return imageHeight;
     }

  }
```

then when accessing your `ViewHolder` in `onBindViewHolder`

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder row, int position) {

   //.... Get the ImageView height
   int imageHeight = row.getImageHeight();
}
```

Comment: That implies, that I set the height in the layout of my `RecyclerView` item, which I can't. :(

Comment: @mars3142 where do you set the Image Height?

Comment: I only can set the height in `onBindViewHolder`. I call **holder.image.setImageBitmap(loadScaledImage(Uri, RecyclerView.height))**. And at this point I need the `RecyclerView` height, for my image scaling.